# How to export Postgresql database, so that it could be used in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I just want to export Postgresql Database to mysql. How can i do that. I tried the GUI of PGadmin 4, but it has no option to export in .sql extension.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.convert-in.com/pgs2sql.htm

Comment: @jeprubio, I don't wanna use external software. What else can be there except that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pg_dump` with the `--format=c --inserts` options to get an SQL file that contains a complete dump of a database.

This certainly won't be loadable into MySQL without modifications. Either edit the file or use a specialized migration tool.

Comment: Laurenz, What type of changes would be needed ? May you explain ?

Comment: No, since I don't know MySQL. But I expect that for example the following statement won't sit well with MySQL: `CREATE TABLE atable (col1 text, col2 public.geometry, col3 inet, EXCLUDE USING gist (col2 WITH &&))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool pg2mysql [pg2Mysql](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php)

[How to use it](https://www.pukkapanel.com/guide29/convert-postgresql-dump-to-mysql)

Alternatively You can use the MySQL Workbench which can import from a variety of database types, including Postgres.

Comment: I have never used Mysql Workbench. I willl try to use it just for this import.